# AVR Input and Output Gauge

Tags: electrical, electrical-distribution

Hello just wanted to know if my AVR has input voltage gauge or output voltage gauge, see sample picture below

[image]

The reason why i'm asking is that my AVR, when turned on, the gauge i'snt all the way up to 220 (my country has 220v as standard). Its somewhere lesser but inside the red line (again see the picture). I just want to make sure since what i knew is that the voltage regulator doesn't regulate properly it could damage my appliance connected to it.

Also, the manual doesn't show any of that ( sad :( ) but yeah any of you guys who are experienced with this stuff, please do share . Thanks

NOTE: BY THE WAY, THE PICTURE IS NOT MINE, GOT IT FROM GOOGLE BUT ITS EXACTLY THE SAME (wattage and all)

Comment: That's a dual scale meter, no way to tellif it's indicating 110 or 220.

Comment: oh man design sux. how would a consumer know if its delivering the exact needed wattage? :(

Comment: With a separate digital voltmeter that might cost all of $5 to $15 unless you want a much fancier one (not needed for this application) - or a $15-20 plug-in meter of the Kill-A-Watt flavor (that will tell you volts, amps, watts, frequency, and power factor.) The built-in one seems to be useless.

Comment: Ditto on the Kill-A-Watt.  I use mine all the time.

Comment: Since it is an AVR it would be indicating the output, so you can verify that it is working correctly.

Comment: dibs on the Kill-A-Watt thingy. hope its avail here in my country :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other Chinese manufacturers of that unit, for example [Ligao](http://www.ligaopower.com/productshow.asp?ID=T499045R39), describe the meter as an **output voltage meter.**

The same design seems to be manufactured by various companies. Sometimes with different sockets (some Sassin units also have 2-pin sockets)

[image]

Comment: i see, maaaan their design really sucks. i did get quite a bargain for my avr but there is no telling if its giving me exactly 220v. meter is off around 5 - 10 points from 220v mark :( but within that red line thingy on 220 mark